# The university didn't sign my I-20. Is that a serious issue?

Tags: visa

I'm an international student newly admitted to a US university. The university already has shipped my I-20 to me. Unfortunately, it happened that they didn't sign my I-20 at all. Mistakenly so, obviously. In my visa interview, the counsel officer noticed that but afterwards she said my visa is approved.

My questions is: will this lack of signature possibly hinder my entrance to the US at the airport?